# PHP concatenate Characters with HTML encoding of the Unicode characters

Tags: php, string, unicode

**PROBLEM**
I am trying to make a string where the values are normal characters as well as HTML encoding.

How can I create a string that is part Character and part Encoding?

**FOR EXAMPLE** 
I want to make an array of the cards A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K of Hearts or &#9829 in HTML encoding.

I have tried the following in *various* forms to no avail...

```
$hearts = array("A&#9829","2&#9829", etc);
```

I have also tried to use the HTML encoding of the letters themselves but it returns an error as unexpected code.

**RESOLVED**
The code as is above will work. Error was due to incorrect " symbols in original php. BUT see selected answer and comments for information on UTF-8 usage in php.

Comment: What's the problem? What's the expected outcome?

Comment: `html_entity_decode("&#9829")` print hears on browser.

Comment: @diEcho I'm not having any problems with outputting the HTML encoding, the problem is when I try to do more with it than have it output (like here create a string).

Comment: @Damien Pirsy, the array isn't created and there is a WARNING, "unexpected...". The arrays would be used aftewards for outputting only.

Comment: @AdamNarbutt that error (did you read it or you just stopped at the "unexpected" word?) has nothing to do with the content of the array, as they're strings. Maybe if you show more of your code we could help you on that.

Comment: @Damien Pirsy, thanks for your patience and replies. The error was caused by my non-english keyboard - I had used the wrong type of " inverted commas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include the UTF-8 characters, for example ❤.

Comment: On output the symbols are not understood. They return ?

Comment: Then use utf-8 as your output charset, as it is already highly recommended. Note, that you must use the internal utf-8 functions for string manipulation then (`mb_*`).

Comment: @Adam: make sure you serve your page with a `meta` tag to set the charset to UTF-8, and save your PHP file as UTF-8.

Comment: @bobince / apfelbox, thanks for the tips! already fairly compliant.. **docs saved** as utf-8, **php** = header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); **html** = <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">, (+ **sql** database/tables utf-8 too, etc) BUT the php manual is 'very light' on **mb_**, and the other sources I've found so far not great. Any good sources of info about multibyte character sets? If no, no problem, thanks anyhows!